# How to force ADO.NET to respect DEFAULT constraint of table-valued parameter?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I have a table type with a DEFAULT constraint:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.T_MY_TABLE_TYPE AS TABLE 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    VALUE VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT ''
)
```

and I use the type for the input parameter of my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_MY_PROCEDURE
(
    @P1 T_MY_TABLE_TYPE READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM @P1
END
```

In T-SQL I can run the SP the following way:

```
declare @p1 dbo.T_MY_TABLE_TYPE;
insert into @p1 values(1, default);
insert into @p1 values(2, NULL);
insert into @p1 values(3, 'abc');

exec dbo.USP_MY_PROCEDURE @P1 = @p1;
```

How can I produce the same script from ADO.NET? I tried the following code:

```
public void MyMethod(List<string> input)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = GetConection())
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("USP_MY_PROCEDURE", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            AddTableParameter(cmd.Parameters, input);
            cmd.Connection.Open();

            using (IDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}

private void AddTableParameter(SqlParameterCollection sqlParameters, IEnumerable<string> input)
{
    SqlMetaData[] metaData =
    {
        new SqlMetaData("ID", SqlDbType.Int, false, true, SortOrder.Ascending, 0),
        new SqlMetaData("VALUE", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64)
    };

    int i = 1;

    var param = new SqlParameter("@P1", SqlDbType.Structured)
    {
        TypeName = "T_MY_TABLE_TYPE",

        Value = input.Select(s =>
        {
            var record = new SqlDataRecord(metaData);
            record.SetInt32(0, i++);

            if (s == null)
                record.SetDBNull(1);
            else if (s == "default")
            {
                //Do nothing. Expect that DEFAULT constraint of T_MY_TABLE_TYPE inserts ''. BUT IT DOES NOT HAPPEN!.
            }
            else
                record.SetString(1, s);

            return record;
        })
    };

    sqlParameters.Add(param);
}
```

However, when I run the following code:

```
    new MyTest().MyMethod(new List<string> { "default", null, "abc" });
```

the script produced by the code ignore DEFAULT constraint:

```
declare @p1 dbo.T_MY_TABLE_TYPE
insert into @p1 values(1, NULL) --This line is wrong!
insert into @p1 values(2, NULL)
insert into @p1 values(3, 'abc')

exec USP_MY_PROCEDURE @P1 = @p1
```

I tried to use [`SqlMetaData.UseServerDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlmetadata.useserverdefault(v=vs.100).aspx) property by replacing this line:

```
new SqlMetaData("VALUE", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64)
```

by this line:

```
new SqlMetaData("VALUE", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64, true, false, SortOrder.Unspecified, -1)
```

but it seems that when I specify `useServerDefault` parameter as true, SQL Server ignores any value I set for the column but always sets the column to its default value. So the result is the following:

```
declare @p1 dbo.T_MY_TABLE_TYPE
insert into @p1 values(1, default)
insert into @p1 values(2, default)
insert into @p1 values(3, default)

exec USP_MY_PROCEDURE @P1 = @p1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Since nobody is going to reply I will try to answer by sharing what I found. The truth is that ADO.NET does not actually 100% support DEFAULT constraint for User-Defined Table Types. Another words, it is not possible to force ADO.NET to respect DEFAULT constraint of table-valued parameter. You can either force it to always use DEFAULT (and ignore any value provided for the column) or never use DEFAULT at all. If you need a mix of default and non-default values in the same operation, the only way is to assign the default value in the application code. As you understand, this is a work-around.